# JavaScript - Global variable not incrementing

Tags: javascript, function, variables, global-variables

My program keeps track of vehicle objects using an array. I have a variable keeping track of the index position of the current car I am showing called **nIndex**. On a button press I call the **nextIMG** function which tries to increment the index and then display the next vehicle. However, doing console.log shows that it is not incrementing. If i set it manually in browser and call nextIMG it works.

I'm really confused as why this should not be working, any help would be appreciated thanks.

```css
var yearID = document.getElementById("year");
var makeID = document.getElementById("make");
var modelID = document.getElementById("model");
var priceID = document.getElementById("price");
var imgID = document.getElementById("picture");

var aVehicles = [];
var nIndex = 0;

addToArray(aVehicles, new Vehicle(2010, "Chevrolet", "Aveo", 6050, "media/aveo.png"));
addToArray(aVehicles, new Vehicle(2012, "Dodge", "Ram", 14398, "media/ram.png"));
addToArray(aVehicles, new Vehicle(2016, "Volvo", "VLN64T 780", 99950, "media/VNL64T780.jpg"));

aVehicles[0].showInfo(yearID, makeID, modelID, priceID, imgID);


//Event Handlers
document.getElementById("btnNext").addEventListener("click", nextIMG);
document.getElementById("btnNext").addEventListener("click", previousIMG);


function Vehicle(year, make, model, price, imagesrc)
{
    this.year = year;
    this.make = make;
    this.model = model;
    this.price = price;
    this.imagesrc = imagesrc;
    this.summarize = function (){
        return this.year + " " + this.make + " " + this.model;
    }
    this.showInfo = function (yearID, makeID, modelID, priceID, imgID) {
        yearID.innerHTML = this.year;
        makeID.innerHTML = this.make;
        modelID.innerHTML = this.model;
        priceID.innerHTML = this.price;
        imgID.src = this.imagesrc;
        imgID.alt = this.summarize();
    }
}

function addToArray(array, object)
{
    array[array.length] = object;
}

function nextIMG() {
    console.log(nIndex);
    nIndex = nIndex + 1;
    console.log(nIndex);
    aVehicles[nIndex].showInfo(yearID, makeID, modelID, priceID, imgID);
    console.log(nIndex);
}

function previousIMG() {
    if (nIndex === 0)
    {
        nIndex = aVehicles.length - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        nIndex--;
    }
    aVehicles[nIndex].showInfo(yearID, makeID, modelID, priceID, imgID);
}
```

Comment: You've got `document.getElementById("btnNext")` twice....

Comment: Ya georg you solved it it all works now Thanks! I was staring at this thing for like 2 hours, looks like i'm blind as a bat. Must have been my mistake of copying and pasting the same line and forgetting to change the id.

Answer (score 0):

You have added listeners calling next and previous function to the same button. Put the second one on btnPrev.

```
  //Event Handlers
document.getElementById("btnNext").addEventListener("click", nextIMG);
document.getElementById("btnPrev").addEventListener("click", previousIMG);
```

Comment: Ya thanks, that was the problem. I wasn't looking in that area at all.